# Why does Azure Data Factory store my ORACLE number(10,0) to PARQUET decimal(38,10) using ADF COPY?

Tags: oracle, decimal, azure-data-factory, parquet

When I open the database in Oracle Developer the datatype of MWD_ID is NUMBER(10,0)
[image: Image 1]

When I check sys.all_tab_columns col the data_length is 22 and precision is 10

[image]

I use the native oracle linked service to make a connection to the Oracle database. The statements are generated based on a list from all the tables I want to export. An example of for the Oracle Query statement as source. The sink is a parquet file. It is not possible to map out certain columns to enforce casting.

[image]

When i load in the parquet file and describe the dataset the format has changed to decimal(38,18)

[image: Image 4]

[image: Image 5]

Comment: are you using DBMS_CLOUD to make the conversion from oracle data types to parquet ?

Comment: No I am using the native 'Copy Task' from Azure Data Factory. Where the SOURCE is the Oracle DB and the SINK is the parquet file.

Comment: ADF coverts Oracle with precision and scale to decimal, even when the scale is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The NUMBER datatype in Oracle stores fixed and floating-point numbers. Numbers
> of virtually any magnitude can be stored and are guaranteed portable
> among different systems operating Oracle Database, up to 38 digits of
> precision.
> Optionally, you can also specify a precision (total number of digits)
> and scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal point):

Regarding your problem, I think your issue is in ADF, not in Parquet.

ADF uses this conversion for Oracle Number when precision and scale are defined:

```
NUMBER (p,s)    Decimal, String (if p > 28)
```

[ADF Oracle data type conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle?tabs=data-factory)

Perhaps you must check with Microsoft Azure Support, because it is clear that it should be transformed to a decimal in ADF, but keeping the precision of 10.